# check returncode in a most small (and elegant) way

Tags: bash, shell

how to make this work?

```
#!/bin/bash
# this code is ugly and does not work
check_if_failed() {
    echo "arg1: $1"
    echo "arg2: $2"
    if [ $1 -ne 0 ] ; then
        exit $1
    fi
}

CHECK="check_if_failed $? $LINENO"

true ; $CHECK
false ; $CHECK

# (edit)
if true ; then
    false ; $CHECK
fi
```

The goal is to have one very small command to check the returncode, so that I can append it to every command line in a simple way.

Comment: Is this not working or are you asking for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is simply

```
some_command || exit
```

As in C, the `||` short-circuits, so its right-hand side only gets evaluated if the left-hand side evaluates to "false" (which is interpreted here as a nonzero return code).

Answer (score 2):

Why adding something after each command you want to check? Let bash do it for you!

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo "Line $LINENO returned $?"' ERR

true
false || :  # this will not be checked
false       # this will be checked
```

Comment: I like this solution, but it is not working with nesting (if,else) or functions. The problem is the ```$LINENO```